# How to use "find" to print the path instead of "grep" in case of matching file contents

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, grep, find

**For example, I need to print the paths of all the user's files that contain the word `hello`.**

**Must use `find`**

Use the `find` command to search, and `grep` to print the path:

```
find ~ -type f -exec grep -lis "hello" '{}' \;
```

Search with the `find` command, and print the path with the `echo` command:

```
find ~ -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -qis "hello" {} && echo {}' \; 2> dev/null
```

**The question now is:**

**How to write a command that prints the file path using *only* `find`? (`grep` can be used to match the string `hello`, but it cannot be used to print the file path. And can't use `sh -c` and `echo`.)**

I tried using `find ~ -type f -exec grep -qis "hello" '{}' \; -printf "%s"` or
`find ~ -type f -exec grep -qis "hello" '{}' \; -print` but it wouldn't output the result (on Ubuntu).

Anyone help?

Comment: Why you can't use grep only in that way: `grep -ris "sed"  ~`. It is not OK for you?

Comment: What do you expect from `-printf "%s"`? With GNU `find` it prints the file size (without a newline). Can't you just use the old good portable `-print`?

Comment: I tried use `-print`, it also don't work

Comment: Well, your `find ~ -type f -exec grep -qis "hello" '{}' \; -print` works for me in Debian 10.

Comment: Your original post contained non-ASCII quote characters. I assumed they were inserted by your browser or something, I corrected them. But if they *really* are in the code you're using then you should fix them. Compare `echo “hello”` and `echo "hello"`. If you're passing `“hello”` to `grep` then no wonder it cannot find `hello`. Please check. This would mean my edit hid the root of the problem.

Comment: it browser changes it, thx to fix it

Comment: You can probably obtain what you want while using "grep -l".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you stated that -print is not working for you, it is possible to use -printf to return a full file path.

```
find ~ -type f -exec grep -qis "hello" '{}' \; -printf "%p\n"
```

according to [find's man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

%p will print the file's name (Which in this context is infact the absolute path)

\n is just adding a newline for the sake of formatting in this example, it's by no means required